# Ethereum Wallet shows 0 balance on Ropsten

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have latest version of Mist. As you can see here https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0227e9a68e3cf3d970247114afefa9444b9a4e09 I have 10 ethers on my account. I waited for days nodes to get updated, I even deleted chaindata and re-synced but my balance is still 0.

Does anyone knows why and how to solve it? This is very buggy software.

I'm using latest Mac OS and latest Ethereum Wallet

Answer (score 0):

The balance you have (10 ETH) is on Ropsten testnet not live ethereum. You can see your real ETH [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0227E9A68E3cF3D970247114aFefa9444b9a4E09) (if you have any)

And make sure your chain is synced with latest block. try running `eth.syncing` and check block number.

And Mist by default connects to live Blockchain.

Comment: Exactly, I need those 10ETH on test network and I swtiched to the test network but no luck. That is the problem: not seeing my balance on test network. It stays 0